# Sorting technique to sort the list of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to sort the list of elements using the javascript/jquery.

But for the first time the sorting is happening which is fine, but if I click again then it should go to the unsorted view.

and the process should go on like this...

Here is the demo link:

[`Sorting Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/mvysZ/)

Comment: Why do you need to sort more than one time?

Comment: Because it is already sorted !

Comment: I think what @ExplosionPills is trying to say is that any sorting function sort() using a given comparison function by definition holds that sort(sort(list)) = sort(list) . So in fact you are sorting every time but the result does not change.

Comment: Do you want the second click to return it to an unsorted view?

Comment: add `console.log(a+':'+b);` inside your sort function to see it work.

Comment: Even I think the same he is looking for a toggle.

Comment: I would add a `$.data()` attribute called `sorted=true|false`, then make the sort function carry out an appropriate action based on that value

Comment: I would suggest to initialize a variabe to some value and then use an `if-else` construct to and assign the variable a different value , so everytime the function gets called would do a toggle.

Comment: When you clicked first time, it's already sorted, what do want to happen when next click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the below code is what you are searching for (sort in ascending order on first click and reverse on next click.):

```
var sort_ascend= true;
    function sort() {
        var mylist = $('#sorting_list ul');
        var listitems = mylist.children('li').get();
        mylist.empty();
        if(sort_ascend){
            listitems.sort(function (a, b) {
                return $(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).text().toUpperCase());
            })
        }
        else{
            listitems.reverse(function (a, b) {
                return $(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).text().toUpperCase());
            })
        }
        sort_ascend = !sort_ascend;
        $.each(listitems, function (idx, itm) { mylist.append(itm); });
    }
```

Comment: I tried but its not working can you please edit my fiddle and sent back with demo